# Isolating batteries from charger

Tags: batteries, charger

I have an interesting project and I don't know whats the best solution.

Basically I have a charger (charges one battery at a time) and 2 batteries.

What I want to do is to have the charger charging battery 1 (while battery 2 is feeding clean power to an audio system)

With a voltage sensor (when battery is low) , I want to switch the charger to battery 2 and have battery 1 power the audio system. (the voltage sensor its not the question)

My question is : The battery that feeds the audio system must be completely isolated from the charger and ground (so no power noise is present).

Is there a way (except SSR) to do that ? 
PCB is quite small and space is at a premium. Also take in consideration and charger is 3A 5.5v and batteries are 5.4v

Comment: you could also use good old relays ^^

Comment: Will the 2nd battery charge more quickly than the 1st will discharge?

Comment: NMOS transistor, but you will need a charge pump. PMOS is easier to implement, but it has greater Rdson for same size. There are also dirvers that have bulilt-in threshold monitor. Try to google: PMOS cahrge pump battery threshold monitor. As for the ground isolation: this is not true, install the minus wire from battery to the audio equipment and ground it near battery.

Comment: Yes battery will charge faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relay would really be the only way to completely isolate the the charging battery subsystem from the consuming battery system. Using solid state components to switch the battery connections would probably be good enough, even with a shared ground, for most applications and users. But technically this still leaves a connection. On the other hand for some audio purists, and it seems that you fall into that category because you are even talking about using batteries to power your audio system, you would have to use a multi-pole relay to connect both the + and - sides of the battery to one system or the other.

Such system could very likely provide your intention of "clean battery power" to the audio system. There are some short comings though -

1. During the switch over from one battery to the other there would be an annoying loss of operational mode of the audio subsystem for a moment.
2. Some audio equipment may give loud pops when the power source is suddenly connected or disconnected.
3. If the charger is not capable of charging one battery faster than than the consumption rate off the other battery then you maximum listening time, with one annoying battery switch over event, would be the time afforded by two charged batteries.

Comment: And (4): You would need to incorporate a circuit to ensure that, in the event of *both* batteries being depleted, you don't enter a race condition such that the relays are constantly switching from one battery to the other.

Comment: @CharlieHanson - Yeah.  :<)   Now we are into the design side and there would be all kinds of things to consider including trying to see if capacitors can somehow prevent most of the pops and sudden power loss that I've mentioned.

Comment: Anyone can point me to smallest multipole relay (SSR) since mechanical relay will make too much noise, defeating the point of having high fidelity audio

Comment: @MichaelKaras Having each relay pole make-before-break will allow for the power to be constantly applied. A capacitor will have to soak up the voltage difference to ward of any nasty transients, but it should be reasonably seamless. That said, Op has not yet alluded to full/dead battery voltages or current consumption, so it's anybody's guess.

Comment: @JohanB. Farnell's range of [MOSFET SSRs](http://uk.farnell.com/solid-state-relays-mosfet/prl/results)

Comment: Battery will last about 3 times longer in audio device than charging battery.  Yes my second concern is power loss once we switch from one battery to another . However batteries are using a boost convertor and I was thinking to add a (super)capacitor that could feed enough power for delay ms we need for the relays to switch. Even , I could make this capacitor have the same voltage as charged batteries (when batteries are fully charged)

Comment: @CharlieHanson On a mecanical relay how do you have each relay pole make-before-break? I do not get how it is feasable on mecanical relay since it is a piece of metal going from one side to another. Except you mean to put 2 relays for each pole?

Comment: @CharlieHanson - Make before break relays in this instance are a very bad idea. You would get huge transient spikes of current as you momentarily connected a depleted battery in with a fully charged battery. One would be trying to charge the other through what would be a momentary short circuit between the two.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I mentioned that the voltage levels for full/dead batteries was not mentioned in the question, and therefore a "make before break" rule is not necessarily the correct option. Inrush current can easily be mitigated, but the acceptability of complexity again hasn't been specified by the OP. An audiophile in search of perfection might not care how much circuitry is required!